# how to format with a Xcelite writer

Tags: java, excel

1. How do I skip columns (include spacing in the middle of my data to make it readable) when writing a new sheet using Xcelite?
2. Is it possible to write two tables on the same sheet with the 2nd table below the 1st?
3. Is Xcelite even the right tool for me to be using? Most of the information that I was able to find on using Excel writing tools for Java is over a decade old. Xcelite is very easy to use but it doesn't seem very customizable and the only documentation I can find for it is their Github page and its light on details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Columns can be skipped by adding an unused field to the pojo and then using the Xcelite @Column annotation to set the value to a space (can't be an empty string) -

```
@Column(name = " ")
private final String space = null;
```

2. Two tables can be written to the same spreadsheet. After writing the 1st table, you simply grab the same sheet via `getSheet` and then proceed as normally and the 2nd table be written right next to it. To place the 2nd table below the 1st, you need to modify the XceliteOptions via the `setHeaderRowIndex`. This needs to be done after writing the 1st dataset and before writing the 2nd.

```
public void write2Tables(List<Data> firstList, List<Stat> secondList, String sheetName) {
    Xcelite xcelite = new Xcelite()
    xcelite.createSheet(sheetName).getBeanWriter(Data.class).write(firstList);
    xcelite.write(outputFile)

    XceliteOptions options = new XceliteOptions();
    options.setHeaderRowIndex(firstList + 2); //single space between tables
    xcelite.setOptions(options);

    xcelite.getSheet(sheetName).getBeanWriter(Stat.class).write(secondList);
    xcelite.write(outputFile)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can skip data rows with `XceliteOptions.firstDataRowIndex` or you can leave blank rows at the top with the header row pushed down with `XceliteOptions.headerRowIndex`.
2. Should be possible if you have `null` values in your bean collection and set the `missingRowPolicy` accordingly. If you want to write to different tables to one spreadsheet with a set of blank rows in between, you should use two different bean collections and close and reopen the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to be able to skip a column in the middle of my data. I have 5 columns of data, and then a space before 3 more columns. I created an extra field in my POJO (set to null) to give it that space but I have to manually delete the column name afterwards.

Comment: @dbrewster I completely misread columns for rows. No, there is no current provision for writing empty columns except for inserting null values